# Bootstrap Nav bar Orientation from LTR to RTL my code attached

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, nav

I have logo on left side of navbar and menu button on right side I want to change navbar orientation such that logo come to the right side and button for menu on left side my code is,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
        <img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;"
             src="./Styles/img/seha1.png">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried one thing to use style `navbar pull right` on the outer side of this nav tag. and on button `navbar pull left` it work but result in increase the width of the navbar

Hopes for your suggestions

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement RTL bootstrap 4 navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935966/how-to-implement-rtl-bootstrap-4-navbar)

Comment: @shidersz same code as above I just use "nav{
    direction:rtl;
}" but it is not effecting my nav :(

Comment: Have you tried the alternative answer there?

Comment: Also, what version of Bootstrap you have, `3.x` or `4.x`?

Comment: I have version 3

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Do it work for your case?

Answer (score 0):

You was right, the solution mentioned in the next link do not work for **Bootstrap 3**:

[How to implement RTL bootstrap 4 navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935966/how-to-implement-rtl-bootstrap-4-navbar)

However, I manage to solve your problem using a custom class named `navbar-rtl` that will customize the `CSS` style of the navbar for give it a `RTL` appearance. I hope this can help you:

```css
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-rtl .navbar-header {
        float: right;
    }
}

.navbar-rtl .navbar-brand {
    float: right;
}

.navbar-rtl .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
}

.navbar-rtl .navbar-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default navbar-rtl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
        Navbar
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```